# trying to show the first array value and then subsequent ones using useState()

Tags: react-hooks

I am getting an array called targets and then doing below -

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
console.log(targets)  //prints the array successfully
console.log(count) //prints 0
console.log(targets[count].name) // this comes as undefined.
```

However, if I do onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} then it successfully displays targets[count].name which is targets[1].name

Why does it not work for targets[0].name

Comment: Where is `targets` coming from? Specifically how is it defined? A bit more context around your code would help. That alone works fine --- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/strange-lovelace-dq26ws

Comment: const {keyStore} = useStore(); 
    const {targets} = keyStore;

    const {id} = useParams();

    useEffect ( () => {
        keyStore.loadTargets(Number(id))   //loadtarget calls the endpoint which returns the array
      }, [targets])

    
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    console.log(targets)  //
    console.log(count)

Comment: sorry...nm..its working now...must be something silly

Answer (score 0):

```js
// code from the comment
const {keyStore} = useStore(); 
const {targets} = keyStore; 
const {id} = useParams(); 

useEffect ( () => { keyStore.loadTargets(Number(id)) }, [targets]) 

const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 

console.log(targets) // console.log(count)
```

Inside `useEffect`, there is a logic that calls the `loadTargets` method in `keyStore` to change the `keyStore` value, and you put the `target` as deps of `useEffect`. I can't give you an exact reason as far as I don't know how the `keyStore` works, but I think `console.log(targets)` was executed when the state of the `keyStore` was not fixed due to the `targets` in the deps of `useEffect` during the process of creating the component.

And in my personal opinion, rather than changing the keyStore value through useEffect, it would be safer to put the logic to change the keyStore in useStore and then change the state through eventHandler!

Hope it helps you :)